# Allocating large space for dynamic array

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

we wrote a program that reads comma-separated integer-values into an array and tries processing them with a parallel structure.
By doing so, we found out that there is a fixed limitation for the maximum size of the dynamic array, which usually gets allocated dynamically by doubling the size. Yet for a dataset with more than 5000 values, we can't double it anymore.

I am a bit confused right now, since technically, we did everything the way other posts pointed out we should do (use realloc, don't use stack but heap instead).

Note that it works fine for any file with less or equal than 5000 values.
We also tried working with realloc, but to the same result.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// compile with gcc filename -lpthread -lm -Wall -Wextra -o test

int reader(int ** array, char * name) {
    FILE *fp;
    int data,row,col,count,inc;
    int capacity=10;
    char ch;
    fp=fopen(name,"r");
    row=col=count=0;
    while(EOF!=(inc=fscanf(fp,"%d%c", &data, &ch)) && inc == 2){
        if(capacity==count)
            // this is the alternative with realloc we tried. Still the same issue.
            //*array=malloc(sizeof(int)*(capacity*=2));
            *array = realloc(*array, sizeof(int)*(capacity*=2));

        (*array)[count++] = data;
        //printf("%d ", data);
        if(ch == '\n'){
            break;
        } else if(ch != ','){
            fprintf(stderr, "format error of different separator(%c) of Row at %d \n", ch, row);
            break;
        }
    }
    // close file stream
    fclose(fp);
    //*array=malloc( sizeof(int)*count);
    *array = realloc(*array, sizeof(int)*count);
    return count;

}

int main(){


    int cores = 8;
    pthread_t p[cores];
    int *array;
    int i = 0;
    array=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    // read the file

    int length = reader(&array, "data_2.txt");
    // clean up and exit
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I included the realloc-command we tried and changed the values back to our original testing values (starting at 10). This didn't impact the result though, or rather still does not work. Thanks anyways for pointing out the errors! I also reduced the included code to the relevant part.

I can't really get my head around the fact that it *should* work this way, but doesn't, so it might just be a minor mistake we overlooked.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any `realloc` around... I only see how you are leaking the memory by repeating using `malloc`.

Comment: 1) How do you know? I don't see you check the result of `malloc` which you should. 2) You have massive memory leaks in the `while` loop.

Comment: Your array is initially allocated as 10 element array but then filled with 50001 elements - so you are messing up your memeory. also you should use realloc or copy your array manually and free the old one. additional to that, i would suggest you to read some coding style guides. your code is really ugly in some places. Additionally you should create a minimal working example of your problem. A lot of your code does not belong to your problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. We tried with realloc, but it didn't work as well. Thanks for the hint, from what i understood it was that malloc would free the old memory as well. I will edit the code momentarily.

Comment: can you post the data-file? or at least the 5000 and 5001 element? The code should work with the fixes from @4386427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> New answer after question has been updated

The use of `realloc` is wrong. Always do `realloc` into a new pointer and check for NULL before overwriting the old pointer.

Like:

```
int* tmp = realloc(....);
if (!tmp)
{
    // No more memory
    // do error handling
    ....
}
*array = tmp;
```

---

> Original answer (not fully valid after question has been updated)

You have some serious problems with the current code.

In `main` you have:

```
array=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);  // This only allocates memory for 10 int

int length = reader(&array, "data_1.txt");
```

and in `reader` you have:

```
int capacity=5001;
```

So you assume that the array capacity is 5001 even though you only reserved memory for 10 to start with. So you end up writing outside the reserved array (i.e. undefined behavior).

A better approach could be to handle all allocation in the function (i.e. don't do any allocation in `main`). If you do that you shall initialize `capacity` to `0` and rewrite the way capacity grows.

Further, in `reader` you have:

```
    if(capacity==count)
        *array=malloc(sizeof(int)*(capacity*=2));
```

It is wrong to use `malloc` as you loose all data already in the array and leak memory as well. Use `realloc` instead.

Finally, you have:

```
*array=malloc( sizeof(int)*count);
```

Again this is wrong for the same reason as above. If you want to resize to the exact size (aka count) use `realloc`

Comment: I apologize for the code. I hastily tried to upload it, which was a huge mistake. The reduced and corrected code is available now, which should point out my original problem rather than disturb you with some hastedly changed values.

Comment: @dennlinger - Don't use `*array = realloc...` If it fails you have lost the previous data. Please check the link I posted for the correct use of `realloc`

Comment: @dennlinger - In what way does the program fail when there are more than 5000 values?

Comment: It simply does not increase the size anymore. Regardless of the input data, it will always end up with the length of 5000. I will try out your sample and get back if it was successful.

Comment: It didn't do anything else than before. It simply does not increase the size past the mark of 5000 objects.
This is my current allocation code: `int *temp = (int*) realloc(array,sizeof(int)*(capacity*=2));`

Comment: @dennlinger - what exactly happen? Does `realloc` return a `NULL` pointer ? BTW - there is no way your code can end up with exactly 5000 objects. How do you observe that there are 5000 objects?

Comment: @dennlinger might be a typo, but you need to use `*array` in the realloc-call